# Typecast a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, string

I have a column with multiple types in it. As in the code below, "col1" has 2 values that are floats but when I take the overall datatype using df['col1'].dtype, it gives the output as "O".

```
 df['col1'].apply(lambda i: type(i)).value_counts()
 <class 'str'>      1094380
 <class 'float'>          2

 df['col1'].dtype
 Out[6]: dtype('O')
```

When I try to do some string computation, it throws an error because of those "float" values. If I try to typecast the entire column, that problem still persists.

Wondering is there a way to just typecast the float values and leave the rest untouched.

Comment: You only have 2 float values, what are they? Is there a chance that they are `NaN` values?

Comment: @QuangHoang: Not sure how to print them, I am trying to do that

Comment: `df.loc[df['col1'].apply(lambda i: isinstance(i, float)), 'col1]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the whole column into string to do string computation using

```
df['column_name'].astype('str')
```